# psql on WSL: Not listing all databases for owner postgres

Tags: psql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to setup Postgres on WSL (bash) to be able to use pg_dump (as an absolute beginner).

I've followed the steps from [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/) twice, once after purging the entire installation.

At step 3: I used

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

as

```
systemctl status postgresql.service
```

returned

```
"System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down"
```

After starting the service using

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

I accessed postgres using

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Here, the list of databases returned are

```
List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

While PostgreSQL shell returns me the list of **ALL** my databases.

```
List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 snappdev  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

[image: SQL Shell]

**snappdev** database is what I'm trying to take a dump of. However, it is not listing on WSL (ubuntu). I also tried changing permissions (chmod / chown). I have made the recommended changes on postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf.

Also, after I do

```
sudo -u postgres
```

I'm constantly being asked for postgres password even when I'm trying to change its password. For this, I've also tried

```
psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'StrongAdminP@ssw0rd'"
```

which keeps asking me the password for the user, and

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

along with other steps recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database).

I'm not really sure at this point what I'm missing or if taken some terribly wrong steps. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What is this "*PostgreSQL shell*" and how do you start it? Is that a Windows program, or do you run that inside the WSL container?

Comment: When you install PostgreSQL on Windows, it comes with an SQL Shell (psql) that runs on Windows.

Comment: So how do you start your `psql` in windows? Please show us the complete command line you are using. Does it connect to the Windows instance or the Linux (=WSL) instance?

Comment: It is independent of Linux. It's a part of Windows' PostgreSQL setup. I've been using it to access my DB for all other purposes.
I've added a snapshot of the same in the question above.

Comment: So with one tool to connect to you Postgres database on Windows and with the other you connect to your Postgres database on Linux - two completely different installations. Why are you surprised they have different databases?

Comment: Ok. I was expecting the one on Linux to be able to access the Windows one. And then be able to take a dump from there. (Since I only found pg_dump that could work via Linux).
(... Apologies for the terrible misunderstanding.)
Would you know if I could take a db dump on Windows itself?

Comment: It might be possible, but not if you run `psql`  on Linux without telling it to connect to a Postgres server (service) running on a different computer. But I have no experience with WSL let alone how to expose a port from the host (=Windows) to the Linux environment

Comment: See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824788/how-to-connect-to-windows-postgres-database-from-wsl

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: Or here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1041981/how-can-i-connect-to-postgres-running-on-the-windows-host-from-inside-wsl2

Answer (score 0):

If you (like me) have PostgreSQL installed on Windows and are trying to take a backup, there's pg_dump.exe utility (which I had not come across before). The steps to take a backup/dump are:

1. Open command prompt.
2. `cd ../..`
3. `cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin`
4. `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres dbname > "path/dumpfile.sql"`